# Dynamic AS when using MySQL Pivot table

Tags: mysql, pivot, case, pivot-table

Wondering if anyone can help, I have an SQL statement thats causing me grief.

My statement using a MAX case() to act as a pivot table, which works fine - but i'm manually applying an AS column name - can this be done dynamically?

Here's my current statement;

```
SELECT
u.prefix AS  'Title', 
u.forename AS  'Forename', 
u.surname AS  'Surname', 
u.email AS  'Email Address', 
u.update_time AS  'Register Date', 
eg.name AS 'Event Group Registered', 
e.name AS  'Session Registered', 
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 1 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Question2',
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 2 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Question2',
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 3 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Question1',
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 4 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Question2',
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 5 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Question1',
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 6 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Question2'

FROM tbl_event_attendees AS ea

LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON ea.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_event AS e ON ea.event_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_groups AS eg on e.group_id = eg.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u2 ON ea.guest_of_user_id = u2.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_user_variables AS uv on u.id = uv.user_id

WHERE ea.event_id =6
GROUP BY ea.id
```

My statement joins a few tables together, including a variable table, where several rows are applicable to specific rows in this table.

So i don't want the name of the column to be 'Question1', but rather the adjacent column 'name' that applies to the `uv.value`, i.e.;

```
MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = 14 THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS uv.name,
```

Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

Comment: You should give more details about your table.

Comment: hi, i've expanded on my statement a bit

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works for you or not, but just try it;)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = ''',
      uv.user_type_variables_id,
      ''' THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS `',
      uv.name, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM tbl_user_variables uv;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT
        u.prefix AS  ''Title'', 
        u.forename AS  ''Forename'', 
        u.surname AS  ''Surname'', 
        u.email AS  ''Email Address'', 
        u.update_time AS  ''Register Date'', 
        eg.name AS ''Event Group Registered'', 
        e.name AS  ''Session Registered'', ',
        @sql, 
        ' FROM tbl_event_attendees AS ea
        LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u ON ea.user_id = u.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_event AS e ON ea.event_id = e.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_event_groups AS eg on e.group_id = eg.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_user AS u2 ON ea.guest_of_user_id = u2.id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_user_variables AS uv on u.id = uv.user_id
        WHERE ea.event_id =6
        GROUP BY ea.id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, get the following error message; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT(  'MAX(CASE WHEN uv.user_type_variables_id = ''', uv.user_type_variables_id,  ''' THEN uv.value ELSE NULL END) AS `', uv.name,  '`' ) ) 
INTO @sql 
FROM tbl_user_variables;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'uv.user_type_variables_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @gsusonline Updated it, check it please.

Comment: Thanks, now getting the following error: #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Comment: What if run this query in mysql console?

Comment: Showing up my limited knowledge of SQL here, how do i run this in console, i don't seem to have any console access on my server?

Comment: using PHPMyAdmin as a DB front end to get the SQL working, but the end result is being called in a PHP function on a web app

Comment: @gsusonline Hmm, got that. This may not work in `PHPMyAdmin `. Perhaps you have to find another solution for your question.

Comment: This solution should be fine.  You do not need she'll access to the server to use the `mysql` command line utility ("console").  You can install it on your workstation and connect to a remote server and the behavior is identical.  The CLI is the gold standard for testing queries.  phpmyadmin is more of a toy that a tool.